# ASP.NET Core 3.1 InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: multithreading, async-await, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.1

I facing some problems in asp.net core 3.1 when using _context.savechanges() or use repository.

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

Here  more information the appear in the browser,

```
if (bill_VM.Custoemr_selected != null)
{
    custId = bill_VM.Custoemr_selected.Id != 0 ? bill_VM.Custoemr_selected.Id : 0;
    _shoppingCart.AddCust(custId);
}
//var selectedItem = await  _context.Items.Where(p => p.Id == itemId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var selectedItem = _itemRepository.GetById(itemId); < ---this point
if (selectedItem != null)
{
    _shoppingCart.AddToCart(selectedItem, itemQty, AdjPrice, userid);
}
return RedirectToAction("SalesIndex", "Sales");
```

my repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    protected void Save() => _context.SaveChanges();
    protected async Task<int> SaveAsync() => await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          ........ // some get and create methods are here
            public T GetById(int Id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(Id);
    }
    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

My ApplicationDbContext

```
     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
        ....... // DbSet
}
```

services

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        //start Repo
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        services.AddTransient<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
```

anyone, please help me. It was working properly. before I using the multip SaveChanges method using transaction. now I come back to my previous code which only I Used one savechanges() . after that I receive this error =>  (A second operation started...).

- =>any async-await problem ...? or
- =>not clearly Dispose() my dbcontext...?  or
- =>need to add any service ..?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception? Can you show how `ApplicationDbContext` is being created?

Comment: @PauloMorgado 
`public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
      
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
       ........   
        }
}`

Comment: We still don't know how the instance is being fed to the constructor of `Repository<T>`.

Comment: @Paulo should i pass T through Repository..? Can u explain clearly?

Comment: We need to know the full stack trace of the exception and how `ApplicationDbContext` is being instantiated to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably believe it is due to Async and Await. I had also faced the same issue earlier but I forgot what I did for this. Try  with synchronous approach if it works.

Comment: yep. now my coding working, thanks for your suggestion. my mistake is some point  I Used `async-await` and sometimes I just use `dbcontext ` without `async-await`,   finally, make it to `await` all my `Asynchronous` call.    [link]( https://thecodebuzz.com/efcore-second-operation-started-context-before-operation-completed/)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on a console app and tried several suggestions including async and wait but none worked.

Finally I added a delay after adding an entity and it worked.

```
                var entity = _context.Contracts.Add(contract_);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);//delay
                var afftected =  _context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use  `ServiceLifetime.Transient`

In startup.cs - ConfigureServices - while configuring your db context

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. Now I'm doing major changes on my coding,  I'll try ur code and come back with the result.  before that can u explain clearly whats that `ServiceLifetime.Transient`. How it is work...? please.!

Comment: It just for setting lifetime of the service, after set db as Transient it will be created for each request, so each thread should have it's own db context 'when request it', read more from the offical docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes

Comment: yep. now my coding working, thanks for your suggestion. my mistake is some point  I Used `async-await` and sometimes I just use `dbcontext ` without `async-await`,   finally, make it to `await` all my `Asynchronous` call (including my `Repository Interface` in DB also changed to `Task` ). and I tried  `ServiceLifetime.Transient` also. but the truth is without `ServiceLifetime.Transient` its working, I'm just using it for safety purpose.  [link]( https://thecodebuzz.com/efcore-second-operation-started-context-before-operation-completed/)